# I want to search an index of an html element

Tags: php

I set the code as --

```
<?php
 function scraping_digg() {   
  // create HTML DOM     
$html = file_get_html('http://www.bigestock.com/product-detail/club-funtrade-tabletop-miniature-pool-table');  
      // get news block  
        foreach($html->find('.cartTable') as $article) {        
     // get title        
       $item['title'] = trim($article->find('td',0)->plaintext);  
       $ret['title'] = $item;       
       print_r($ret['title']); 
                 } 
    //clean up memory   
     $html->clear();     
     unset($html);     
     return $ret; 
}?>
```

I want:

```
Array ( [title] => Club Fun™ Tabletop Miniature Pool Table )
```

this answer, but it is returning

```
Array ( [title] => Club Fun™ Tabletop Miniature Pool Table ) Array ( [title] => Brands )
```

Please help me to find the desired answer.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
foreach($html->find('.cartTable') as $article) {        
 // get title        
   $item['title'] = trim($article->find('td',0)->plaintext);  
   $ret['title'] = $item;       
   print_r($ret['title']); 
}
```

do something like -

```
foreach($html->find('.cartTable') as $article) {        
 // get title        
   $item['title'] = trim($article->find('td',0)->plaintext);  
   $ret['title'][] = $item;       
} 
print_r($ret['title'][0]);
```